# NullPointerException (corrected)

Tags: java, android

I'm back again with another NullPointerException. It says that there is an error at the marked line. However I can't figure out what is causing the problem. I'm sure that the id's are right and do exist.

Here is my code:

MainActivity.java:

```
    package com.bartkoppelmans.wavelength;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ComponentName;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.ServiceConnection;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.view.GestureDetector;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.TimeZone;
    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {

        GestureDetector gestureDetector;

        public static final boolean isCreated = false;
        public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        Timer timer;
        boolean musicBound=false;
        private MusicService musicService;
        private Intent playIntent;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector( this );

            ImageView playButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.albumImageView);
            playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    playButtonPressed();
                }
            });

            FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.musicSelectionOpenerFrameLayout);
            frameLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MusicSelection.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up_in, R.anim.slide_up_out);
                }
            });
        }

        //connect to the service
        public final ServiceConnection musicConnection = new ServiceConnection(){

            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                MusicService.MusicBinder binder = (MusicService.MusicBinder)service;
                //get service
                musicService = binder.getService();
                musicBound = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                musicBound = false;
            }
        };

        //start and bind the service when the activity starts
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            if(playIntent==null){
                playIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
                bindService(playIntent, musicConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                startService(playIntent);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
            super.onNewIntent(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_down_in, R.anim.slide_down_out);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
            super.onStop();
        }

        public void playButtonPressed() {
            if  (isCreated)  {
                if ( mediaPlayer.isPlaying() ) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                } else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            }else {
                updateTimer();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select song", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent start, MotionEvent finish, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(me);
        }

        public void updateTimer() {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
----------------------------final TextView timerTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);
                            final ProgressBar timerProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.mainProgressbar);
                            if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                                timerTextView.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        int position = 5;
                                        int duration = 10;
                                        timerProgressBar.setMax(duration);
                                        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                                        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                                        final String time = df.format(new Date(position)) + " / " + df.format(new Date(duration));
                                        timerTextView.setText(time);
                                        timerProgressBar.setProgress(position);
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                timer.cancel();
                                timer.purge();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 0, 100);
        }

    }
```

MusicService.java:

```
package com.bartkoppelmans.wavelength;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Timer;

public class MusicService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

    //media player
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    //binder
    private final IBinder musicBind = new MusicBinder();
    Timer timer;
    Handler handler;

    public void onCreate(){
        handler = new Handler();
        //create the service
        super.onCreate();
        //create player
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        //initialize
        initMusicPlayer();
    }

    public void initMusicPlayer(){
        //set player properties
        mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(),
                PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        //set listeners
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    }

    //binder
    public class MusicBinder extends Binder {
        MusicService getService() {
            return MusicService.this;
        }
    }

    //activity will bind to service
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return musicBind;
    }

    //release resources when unbind
    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        return false;
    }

    //play a song
    public void playSong(Uri songUri){
        //play
        mediaPlayer.reset();

        //set the data source
        try{
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), songUri);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e);
        }
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

        MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
        mainActivity.updateTimer();
    }

    public void setSong(Uri newSongUri)  {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
        //getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);

        playSong(newSongUri);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int what, int extra) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        //start playback
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    private void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) {
        handler.post(runnable);
    }

    public int getDuration(){
        int duration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        return duration;
    }
    public int getPosition(){
        int position = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        return position;
    }
}
```

Java stack trace:

```
12-31 15:52:40.088  28371-28371/com.bartkoppelmans.wavelength E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.bartkoppelmans.wavelength, PID: 28371
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1965)
            at com.bartkoppelmans.wavelength.MainActivity$4$1.run(MainActivity.java:161)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do you get the NPE consistently? Is the Activity on screen while you get the NPE? Do you rotate the device, switch apps and back? **What steps are required to reproduce?**

Comment: "I'm sure that the id's are right and do exist." - there's your problem.  The JVM is always right.  Check your assumptions.  A spin through a debugger will sort this out quickly.  Get a good IDE like IntelliJ and learn how to do it.

Comment: Yes, I do. And yes, it occurs when I click on an item in the listView. This (indirectly) triggers updateTimer(). Then the NPE is shown.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ and it doesn't give any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this to communicate between and Activity and a Service

Inside your `MusicService`:

```
    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    mainActivity.updateTimer();
```

Your null pointer is because when you say `new MainActivity()` the activity you create is not attached to the lifecycle and so `onCreate` and other methods are not called therefore, no `onCreate` means no `setContentView` meaning all views found with `findViewById` are null

To communicate between services and activities use one of the following methods:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html#servicecommunication

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger

Comment: I +1 because I recognised (as in, "you better recognise" validity of answer)

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is the problem. Now I'm off to go problem-solving! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It is, really, awfully hard to debug this, using the information you've supplied.  As @duffymo says, the VM is *always* right.  The way to solve an NPE is to look at the stack trace, go to the corresponding line in your code and, on that line, fine the variable that is null.

In your case, the error is caused because there is no root view in the instance of `MainActivity` that you create in `playSong`.  `findViewById` expects an installed view and fails when it is null.

You may not create new instances of Activity and expect them to behave normally.  Only the framework can do that.  You'll probably need to find a way to update the timer from MainAcitivity.onStart.